# SQL syntax error in phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I am creating a small CMS for a school assignment and I tried this piece of SQL code in phpMyAdmin:

```
INSERT INTO subjects (
                menu_name, position, visible
            ) VALUES (
                '{Test item}', {4}, {1}
            )
```

But it doesn't works. It tells me:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '4}, {1} )' at line 4.

Could someone please explain to me what I am doing wrong.

Comment: wat data type is position and visible? if they are chars or varchars you'll need to surround with ''

Comment: What are your brackets for?  Don't use those...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why adding braces? This should work:

```
INSERT INTO subjects (
  menu_name, position, visible
) VALUES (
  'Test item', 4, 1
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast reaction. It works. Thank you!!

Comment: @user2048338 No problem. Don't forget to accept one of our answer in order to close the question.

Answer (score 1):

dont use brackets , try this

```
 INSERT INTO subjects (
            menu_name, position, visible
        ) VALUES (
            'Test item', 4, 1
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless the field actually requires braces you won't include them.

```
INSERT INTO `subjects` (`menu_name`,`position`,`visible`) VALUES('Test Item', 4, 1)
```